# Do I have to take up linoleum?

Tags: flooring

I am putting down LVP in my basement concrete floor with linoleum on it now. Do I have to take up the linoleum. The edges are curling can I just remove those? Also in the middle of the floor have deep scratches will that affect the LVP?

Comment: Does the LVP you are laying need an underlayment?

Comment: Removing the curled edges will leave voids, which could (will) imprint on the new surface

Comment: Is it linoleum/marmoleum or is it vinyl? Natural linoleum puts off oil which might have a chance of messing with the adhesive on your LVP.

Comment: LVP can go over sallow holes, about 2/16.  The instructions should say.  It is dips/ridges in the floor surface that are important to fix, should be able to lay a long straight edge over the floor and only see very small shivers of light if any at all.

Comment: I disagree that voids will imprint on the surface.  It's LVP, not sheet vinyl.  However, if you want to leave the lineoleum, I wouldn't bother removing the curled edges.  The weight of the LVP is likely to simply press the curls down.